# MvxBind Error View type not found

Tags: mvvmcross

i have seen stuart answers explaining the meaning of this error, and when it can be ignored.

I currently have this error with custom controls referenced in an android layout which is consumed by an MvxFrame control.

One of these control is in an external lib and works perfectly.

Another one is an Mvx derived control and was in the main droid project. I moved it to a lib project, updated namespaces, and puh ! No more warning ... but no more control displayed in the app. And no crash and no log at all :(

idea needed !

Comment: Please include links to things like "stuart answers explaining the meaning of this error, and when it can be ignored." and code samples where possible. For this particular error I suspect you haven't added your custom assembly to https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Platform/MvxAndroidSetup.cs#L246 - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Customising-using-App-and-Setup#providing-custom-views-android - one example is https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Cheesebaron.MvvmCross.Bindings/blob/master/Sample.Android.UI/Setup.cs

Comment: Aha you're the best. I've open so much tabs this week that i have been unable to find again the stackoverflow entry where i have seen this answer. And i was so upset about moving a file to a lib which took me 4 hours of googling before giving up ... I should have read the wiki again.

Comment: Wiki is in fact too messy. There is no relation between this and "customizing using app and setup".

Comment: I have been unable to find the origin of the problem, as the app was working ok for one of the custom control but not for another. And without adding anything to AndroidViewAssemblies

Comment: I'll check tomorrow if it really works.